# Polymer URL mapping

Tags: routes, polymer

Using iron pages is there anyway to map a URL to a different file? In my case it would just be /login to Login.phtml (case-sensitive,) but there may be other cases.

Comment: You want to route `/login` to Login.phtml which I assume is a php page unrelated to your polymer based single page app?

Comment: I actually just wanted to be able to capitalize my filename (Login.html)

Answer (score 1):

Please do not use caps in file names.

using caps in polymer will translate to dash-case, so ThisIsACoolName will translate to this-is-a-cool-name. It might be a personal preference, but i would suggest to just keep it lower-case.

Comment: Is this a written standard?

Comment: using caps in polymer will translate to dash-case, so ThisIsACoolName will translate to this-is-a-cool-name. It might be a personal preference, but i would suggest to just keep it lower-case.

Comment: What if I wanted to simplify User/Form/Login.html to /login?

Comment: Are you using app-routing and app-location? those two in combination with iron-pages works great and seems like that is what you are looking for. Just google Polymer (2) app routing.

Comment: I am, I'll check it out.

Comment: just follow this tutorial https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/toolbox/routing note that this is for polymer 1, and not 2. This is for 2.x https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/toolbox/routing

Comment: I mean I have a lot of the routing all done I just prefer capitals in my file names :P I was wondering if this was a limitation.